# ionic fails to add iOS platform

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, cross-platform

when I try the following command in VS Code

```
sudo ionic cordova platform add iOS
```

I get an error with the following:

```
ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
    
    cordova platform add ios exited with exit code 1.
    
    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

I get iOS folder in platforms folder, but how to solve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

First, why are you running with sudo? I would recreate the project in a directory which does not require this. For example ~/dev/myProjectName

Second, when you scroll up it should give a more specific error.

Third, if not have you tried doing as shown and run with --verbose flag?

Fourth, try opening platform/ios project in xCode and running from there. It may give more useful info.

Comment: When I try to do it without sudo, sometimes it doesn't go. so, I do it with sudo.

I tried to search for specific error code, but I can't find it. I'll post the full log if you need it.

I tried to open the generated Xcode project file, but it didn't build successfully